# How to make MYSQL query results ORDER BY conditions order?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

My query string is like:

```
SELECT ... FROM maintable
LEFT JOIN table1 on (maintable.id = table1.idx)
LEFT JOIN table2 on (table1.idy = table2.idy)
LEFT JOIN table3 on (table2.idz = table3.idz)
WHERE (condition1 OR condition2 OR condition3)
AND maintable.status = static

//condition1 & condition2 & condition3 are kind of
table3.idz = 101, table3.idz = 3, maintable.id IN (1,2,3,4), and so on
```

For the results I want entries that meet `condition1` to be returned first, then entries that meet `condition2`, and finally entries that meet `condition3`. Any ideas?

Comment: Are your conditions distinct? If not, what if an entry meets multiple conditions? For example, if an entry meets conditions 1 and 3, how should it be sorted compared to an entry that meets conditions 1 and 2?

Comment: no restrict here, so i think maybe first meet first return?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

To get the sorting in the order you want, use your conditions in the ORDER BY, but use `DESC` after them.

```
SELECT *
FROM person
WHERE (condition1 OR condition2 OR condition3)
AND maintable.status = static
ORDER BY
    condition1 DESC,
    condition2 DESC,
    condition3 DESC
```

If this doesn't work because your query is more complex, then you can use boolean logic to change your query `(A OR B OR C) AND D` into `(A AND D) OR (B AND D) OR (C AND D)` then you can use the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM person
WHERE (condition1 OR condition2 OR condition3)
AND maintable.status = static
ORDER BY
    condition1 AND static DESC,
    condition2 AND static DESC,
    condition3 AND static DESC
```

The `AND static` is not necessary here because all rows return it, but in a more complex example (where you also return some rows which are not static) then you would have to do it in this way.

Comment: how about the condition (i have my query string updated) is like table.id = 123 ? I have tried ORDER BY sentence, but no effect.

Comment: @Relax: The example I gave before would work fine. I've updated it anyway because I'm guessing that your actually query is more complex than you will allow us to know about.

Comment: You are definetly right! I did not realized that DESC is neccessary even the condition is like table.id=123. Now i have it added and it works like a charm, thanks so much!

Comment: Why DESC is needed by the way?

Comment: Because TRUE is equal to 1, and FALSE is 0. If you want the true values first you have descending order.

Answer (score 9):

This should work:

```
ORDER BY condition1, condition2, condition3
```

for example

```
ORDER BY (weight > 500), (height > 3), (height < 2)
```

Comment: thanks, but it's not work, it may because my actual query string is more complex, i have it updated