# Order results to match the order of values in a WHERE IN expression

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way I can make mysql return results from a Member database by the order I ask it by in the WHERE command?

```
SELECT * 
FROM Members 
WHERE MemberID = "6" 
OR MemberId="3" 
OR MemberID="5"
```

Currently it will return results ordered by MemberID ASC no matter what I do. I want it to return by 6,3,5 i.e. in the order that I ask it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
Select * from Members
WHERE MemberID = "6" or MemberId="3" or MemberID="5"
ORDER BY MemberID = "6" DESC, MemberId="3" DESC, MemberID="5" DESC;
```

Comment: And what if we want to limit results?

Answer (score 36):

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  Members 
WHERE 
  MemberID IN ("6","3","5")
ORDER BY 
  FIELD(MemberID,"6","3","5");
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM Members
ORDER BY CASE MemberId
    WHEN 6 THEN 1
    WHEN 3 THEN 2
    WHEN 5 THEN 3
    ELSE 999
END
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Select * from Members WHERE MemberID = "6" or MemberId="3" or MemberID="5" order by 
MemberID = "6" desc 
MemberId="3" desc
MemberID="5" desc
```

See this post once

[How to make MYSQL query results ORDER BY conditions order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612914/how-to-make-mysql-query-results-order-by-conditions-order)

Answer (score 1):

Try selecting the data using 3 `UNION ALL` queries:

```
SELECT * FROM Members WHERE MemberID = "6"
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Members WHERE MemberId = "3"
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Members WHERE MemberID = "5"
```

or maybe you need to simply add a new column to hold the sort order ?

Answer (score 0):

no.

you must specify an ORDER BY clause to get things into any repeatable order.

If you can construct some logic that specifies the order then you can include that in the ORDER BY otherwise, you cannot.

You may consider adding another data construct to map your 'random' values to a sequence or other ordering value, then using that.