# Gotta catch all products that have the greatest amount

Tags: php, mysql, sql

With the following sample data, I need to get all the products that the amount is 20 because it's the largest quantity. I tried this query however does not seem to work for me because I cannot set the `LIMIT` to the proper amount since I do not know how many products have that quantity.

```
SELECT * FROM Product
ORDER BY Quantity DESC
LIMIT 2

+----+---------+----------+
| Id |  Name   | Quantity |
+----+---------+----------+
|  5 | Pencil  |       20 |
|  8 | Stapler |       20 |
|  4 | Pen     |        5 |
|  9 | Sheet   |        3 |
+----+---------+----------+
```

I need get the products that have most quantity, not necessarily 20, 20 is just an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to select all the products with maximum value of `Quantity` use:

```
SELECT *
FROM Product 
WHERE Quantity = (SELECT MAX(Quantity) FROM Product);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want all results where the Quantity is 20, then all you need to do is specify that in the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT * FROM Product WHERE Quantity = 20;
```

There's no need to include the ORDER BY if you expect the value to be the same throughout. There's also no need to LIMIT unless you want the first number of results where Quantity is 20.

Comment: I need get the products that havê more in quantity, not necessarily 20, 20 was just an example.

Comment: Then you'd simply use >, <, <=, >= to decide on your value. 'WHERE Quantity > 20', 'WHERE Quantity <= 20', 'WHERE 50 > Quanity > 10', etc.

Comment: Sorry but I think you misunderstood me, Craig please re read my question

Comment: @Felipe Vagner - I don't understand. No matter what, you're going to have to specify some sort of variable in a WHERE clause to access quantity. You can change the value to whatever you want. Are you trying to do this dynamically with a script or something.

Answer (score 1):

if You want to compulsorily use `orderby` and `desc` just try

`Select * from Product
WHERE Quantity = 20 
ORDER BY quantity DESC;`

[formore details on orderby and desc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666152/mysql-order-by-where)But it is not mandatory in your sitiation

Answer (score 1):

Since you edited the question, you would get those with 20 or above, sorted greatest to least with the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM Product
WHERE Quantity => 20
ORDER BY Quantity DESC;
```