# Sorting/Ordering MySQL with two fields

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table sort of like this:

```
Product   Price   Sale
------------------------
Watch     10.00    6.00
Socks      8.00
Pen        4.00
Lamp      15.00   12.00
```

Is there an easy way I can order the products by lowest price?

If the sale column has a value I want to use that instead of the price column.
So sorted by price ascending I'd get:

```
Pen
Watch
Socks
Lamp
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use coalesce to achieve what you are looking for.

```
select * 
  from mytable
order by  coalesce(Sale, Price) ASC
```

Coalesce give you the first not null value.

Comment: So simple- easy when you know how :) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2612960/476917) can help you. I think what you want to know is how we could do sorting by condition right?

Comment: COALESCE from Steve works more simply here- thanks for the link though, will keep this in mind for trickier queries!

Comment: @penpen yeah, I see the answer is more simpler :)